# How do you embed an image in an NSAttributedString?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to create an `NSAttributedString` that includes an `NSImage` for an OS X application.

I have tried a few different ways, but with this basic code:

```
let image = NSImage(named: "super-graphic")!

let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = image

let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
```

When I set this on an NSLabel, or NSTextField attributed string, the image doesn't render.

**Is it possible to combine `NSImage` and `NSAttributedString` to embed an image in an attributed string on OS X?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel silly, this code works:

```
let image = NSImage(named: "super-graphic")!
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
let cell = NSTextAttachmentCell(imageCell: image)
attachment.attachmentCell = cell
let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
```

The key difference was to avoid using the "image" property of the `NSTextAttachment`